# Height of TableViewCell is longer than needed

Tags: ios, autolayout

I have a UIView inside of TableViewCell that sets the cell’s height dynamically. But something’s strange. I have a bottom constraint for the bottom label as 8 but the display shows me a gap that’s longer than what I’ve set. Here’s the display:

[image]

And here are my constraints for the bottom UILabel:

[image] [image]

What do I do?

Comment: Seems that bottom label is missing a constraint, from what I see label's width can't be calculated. Doesn't Xcode showing an error? This may be the problem.

Comment: @azimov It sets the width dynamically too. I never set my widths for the labels that changes its width in each cell and never got any error.

Comment: so you don't get any autolayout errors at all, right ?

Comment: Have you tried to set the label `[label sizeToFit]`?

Answer (score 0):

it may not be the constraints - change the background colour of your label to see where it actually extends.  The label text will be shown in the middle of the label - unless you have specified differently.  It looks like your rowHeight is more than you need, and the label is taller than you expect.

If you need the bottom label to sit along the bottom of the row, then specify height rather than top constraint, and tie it to the bottom of the row.